# If $f^n$ measurable for all $n>4$ then $f$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback on this question.

Comment: Is $f^n$ the function that takes $x$ to $f(f(f(\cdots f(x)\cdots)))$ or to $f(x)^n$?

Comment: And: Do you mean for some $n>4$ or for all $n>4$?

Comment: Here $f(x)^n$ like $f^2$.

Comment: $f=(f^5)^{1/5}$ and $x \mapsto x^{1/5}$ is measurable.

Comment: Why $f^2$ is measurable we can not say $f$ is measurable then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shalop said, since $f^5$ is measurable, we have
\begin{align*}
\{f \leq a\} = \{f^5 \leq a^5\}
\end{align*}
which is measurable for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

To address your comment, it is not clear how to write $\{f \leq a\}$ as an expression of sets of the form $\{f^2 \leq b\}$ with $b \in \mathbb{R}$, since $\{f^2 \leq b\} = \{|f| \leq b^{1/2}\}$, not $\{f \leq b^{1/2}\}$.

Comment: So could we say for $f^{2k+1}$ it is true?